# Log out a user from the server

Tags: meteor

Is there any way to log out a user (or all users) from the server? Basically I'm trying to log out all users every time the meteor server starts up or restarts.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could clear up all the `loginTokens` which would force everyone to log back in

```
Meteor.users.update({}, {$set: { "services.resume.loginTokens" : [] }});
```

What this does is it clear's each users loginTokens so that they wont match up if the user tries to log in, then they would have to log back in. To alter who to target change the initial query (currently `{}`)

Comment: update failed: Access denied i got this error , i've use the _id : userId too

Comment: @RaquibulIslam Its best to do this from the server end.

Comment: @RaquibulIslam Run this on server

Comment: I believe this will only log out one user, since `update` only updates the first found document. To log out all users, you'd have to add a third argument to become `Meteor.users.update({}, {$set: { "services.resume.loginTokens" : [] }}, {multi:true});`